# I need help in this (Sums In Loops)

Tags: java

Hello Guys i just need help this is the problem I want to solve:

> Input data will contain the total count of pairs to process in the
>   first line.
>
> The following lines will contain pairs themselves - one pair at each
>   line.
>
> Answer should contain the results separated by spaces.

Example:

```
data:
3
100 8
15 245
1945 54

answer:
108 260 1999
```

i write the code and here it is

```
public class SumsInLoopAdvanced {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = reader.nextInt();
        int a =0;
        int arr [] = new int[250];
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            arr[i] = reader.nextInt();
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            arr[j] = reader.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
                a = arr[j]+arr[i];
            }
            System.out.print("Answer: \n" + a);            
        }      
    }

}
```

it just 245+15 the wrong answer so could you help me ??

Comment: am just curious: why ***new int[250];*** if you are looping until **num**?

Comment: @EJoshuaS Actually 500 numbers! The first 250 are ignored. Still better UX than some things I've worked on in the past ;)

Comment: Do you need to use an array? It's actually a lot simpler without them.

Answer (score 0):

your code is broken here:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
        arr[j] = reader.nextInt();
    }
```

because you are overwriting the previously filled array: `arr[i]`

```
    int arr [] = new int[250];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        arr[i] = reader.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: how to fix it please

Comment: you can define 2 arrays instead...#

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the values in `arr` on your second loop.

If you want to collect two sets of values, you'll need two arrays. (Well, not *need*, but that would be the reasonable way.) Also note that you don't need or want the *nested* loop at the end; just add the `i`th entry from the first array to the `i`th entry of the second.

Side note: Instead of a hardcoded upper bound on the array (`250`), use `num` so you know it's always big enough (e.g., if I tell you I'm going to enter 300 numbers, your code will blow up). `int[] arr = new int[num];`

---

**But**, now that the problem you're trying to solve is quoted in the question, note that your code *doesn't* want to read in a bunch of values, then read in a second bunch of values, and then add those together. The assignments says you'll enter things like "100 8" and then "15 245" and be meant to add those to get `108` and `260`.

So you'll need to read the first number, then the second, add those and store them in your (one) array; then read the next third number, and the fourth, add those together and store them; and then output the results.

Answer (score 0):

If i got it right you need to print a sum of two arrays entries for each index.
First of all you are using the same array and you are overwriting everything that you did in a first loop by the second loop.

```
int arr [] = new int[250];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        arr[i] = reader.nextInt();
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
        //writing into the same array starting with 0 index
        arr[j] = reader.nextInt(); 
    }
```

And if I got this exercise right you don't need a nested loop, you need to to find a sum of two array elements from different arrays with the same index.

something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
       a = arr1[i] + arr2[i];
       System.out.print(a + " ");
      }
```

Comment: Look more closely at the quoted assignment.